# Why does switchMap use in pipe in typescript now require Observable<> for 2nd arg?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6

So upgrading an angular project from 5 to 7.   I migrated my RxJs chains to use pipe.   I do alot of querying and hence use switchMap to do lookups; but typescript and RxJs 6.2 now want me to cast the switchMap return type as Observable, where it did not before. Maybe this is a problem with implicit typing in RxJs? shouldn't switchMap always return an Observable?  For example:

Before:

```js
function GetFoo() : Observable<IFoo>
// ...
GetFoo.pipe(switchMap<IFoo,IBar>(foo => GetBarObservable(foo))
   .subscribe(bar => {
     console.log(bar) 
   });
```

Now needs to be:

```js
function GetFoo() : Observable<IFoo>
// ...  note 2nd arg is now Observable<IBar>
GetFoo.pipe(switchMap<IFoo,Observable<IBar>>(foo => GetBarObservable(foo))
   .subscribe(bar => {
     console.log(bar) 
   });
```

Code works fine once changed and none of the tools complained, but not sure I understand why?

Comment: If I remember correctly in Angular 7 they changed the `.tsconfig` compiler option for `noImplicitAny` to `true`. Maybe check this or explicitly set it to false?